# HTML5 Document uploader and viewer

Tags: html, document, documentviewer

I have a website which is developed in PHP which allows users to add and view documents. The upload process and viewer is very basic in that the user manually enters in what they want to upload and then they can view it on a webpage with basic formatting.

I want to enhance this part of the website so its very similar to the way documents (e.g. doc/docx, pdfs, gifs, jpegs etc) are uploaded and viewed on the Scribd website. It would be preferable that its done in HTML 5 so it is compatible with most browsers and tablets without the need to download additional add ons.

I know that Crocodoc has an API that can do what I'm asking for but they charge a monthly fee, I was hoping to find something cheaper and a lot more cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

upload is done via flash - there are literally hundreds of flash uploaders out there. google will find you what you need.

the viewing part is tricky. crocodoc seems to use a rendering engine in the backend that converts the files into html... cannot help you there

Comment: oh thanks for downvoting... very nice. that's one way of saying "thank you"